# This is a Data Structures Project with array based list functions and I can't seem to get rid of this infinite loop.

Tags: c++, data-structures, dev-c++

I am getting an infinite loop with this project and I can't seem to get around it after working seven hours. Would you please provide some help? This is a project to create a menu based program with array based list functions. I have been researching Cplusplus forums and stackoverflow but can't seem to figure this out. eyesBurning

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#define MAX 15
using namespace std;

main()
{
int array[15];
int n;

printf("Enter the number of elements :");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{   
    printf("Enter the Array elements one by one : ");
    scanf("%d",&array[i]); // seem to be getting an infinite loop here

}
while(n > 1)
{

    printf("\n1. ADD");
    printf("\n2. INSERT");
    printf("\n3. DELETE");
    printf("\n4. SHOW");
    printf("\n5. COUNT");
    printf("\n6. CLEAR");
    printf("\n7. exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
        printf("Enter the new element to add at end: ");
        int new_el;
        scanf("%d",&new_el);
        array[n]=new_el;
        n++;
        break;  
        }   


        case 2:
        {
        printf("Enter the position you want to insert : ");
        int pos;
        int new_el;
        scanf("%d",&pos);
        printf("Enter the new element to insert in that position : ");
        scanf("%d",&new_el);
        pos--;
        for(int i=n-1;i>=pos;i--)
        array[i+1]=array[i];
        array[pos]=new_el;
        n++;
        break;  
        }   

        case 3:
        {
        printf("Enter the value to be deleted : ");
        int key,f=0;
        int pos;
        scanf("%d",&key);
        for(pos=0;pos<n;pos++)
        {
            if(array[pos]==key)
            {
                f=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(pos==n || f==0)
        {
            printf("Element not found");
            break;
        }
        if(f==1)
        {
            for(int i=pos;i<n;i++)
            array[i]=array[i+1];
            printf("Element deleted successfully");
            n--;
            break;
        }
        }
        case 4:
        {
        printf("\n Array elements are");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("\n %d",array[i]);
        break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
        printf("Count is:%d ",n);
        break;  
        }   

        case 6:
        {
        printf("Array is cleared & initialized");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        array[i]=0;
        break;
        }   

    case 7:
    {
        printf("Quit"); 
        return(0);
        break;
    }   
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop runs fine for me. It doesn't get into an infinite loop. Are you trying to enter more than 15 items in your array? If you are, that would be the problem. You'd overwrite `n` with the 16th value.

Comment: Are you sure about the position of the infinite loop? The first for loop is working properly assuming that the value entered for n is less than 15, which is the limit of your array (it is better to display this limit to the user or allocate the array dynamically based on the value entered by the user).

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I was testing it wrong but still got infLoop. Fixed it though it was with while call. Thank You for your immediate attention to my request.

Answer (score 0):

Wil, Use this code i programmed in Linux, so removed windows.h, add back at your end. Problem was with while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 15
using namespace std;

main()
{
int array[15];
int n;

printf("Enter the number of elements :");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{   
    printf("Enter the Array elements one by one : ");
    scanf("%d",&array[i]); // seem to be getting an infinite loop here

}
```

> while(n < MAX)

```
{

    printf("\n1. ADD");
    printf("\n2. INSERT");
    printf("\n3. DELETE");
    printf("\n4. SHOW");
    printf("\n5. COUNT");
    printf("\n6. CLEAR");
    printf("\n7. exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
        printf("Enter the new element to add at end: ");
        int new_el;
        scanf("%d",&new_el);
        array[n]=new_el;
        n++;
        break;  
        }   


        case 2:
        {
        printf("Enter the position you want to insert : ");
        int pos;
        int new_el;
        scanf("%d",&pos);
        printf("Enter the new element to insert in that position : ");
        scanf("%d",&new_el);
        pos--;
        for(int i=n-1;i>=pos;i--)
        array[i+1]=array[i];
        array[pos]=new_el;
        n++;
        break;  
        }   

        case 3:
        {
        printf("Enter the value to be deleted : ");
        int key,f=0;
        int pos;
        scanf("%d",&key);
        for(pos=0;pos<n;pos++)
        {
            if(array[pos]==key)
            {
                f=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(pos==n || f==0)
        {
            printf("Element not found");
            break;
        }
        if(f==1)
        {
            for(int i=pos;i<n;i++)
            array[i]=array[i+1];
            printf("Element deleted successfully");
            n--;
            break;
        }
        }
        case 4:
        {
        printf("\n Array elements are");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("\n %d",array[i]);
        break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
        printf("Count is:%d ",n);
        break;  
        }   

        case 6:
        {
        printf("Array is cleared & initialized");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        array[i]=0;
        break;
        }   

    case 7:
    {
        printf("Quit"); 
        return(0);
        break;
    }   
}
}
}
```

Let me know in case of any clarification!!

Comment: Dhanajay,  This worked out just fine. I made the changes to the while call. It works just fine. I appreciate your attention to my request.

Comment: Will, Thanks for the confirmation. Please accept my answer.